# Curl with URL containing colons e.g. ipv6 addresses

Tags: curl

I'm trying to get the geo data of an ipv6 address using

`curl 'https://demo.ip-api.com/json/2a01:4f9:c011:7ad7::1?fields=66842623&lang=en'`

It's not working because the colon is interpreted as separator for specifying the port.

Is there any chance to make the request with curl?

Using the URL in a browser or with PowerShells' Invoke-WebRequest it works fine.
URL-escaping the colon doesn't work either.

Comment: This is a wrong conclusion as @hanshenrik replied. It is *not* a problem with the colons.

Answer (score 1):

You're using unix quoting rules on Windows.. On Windows, maybe try just using `"` instead of `'` ie

```
curl "https://demo.ip-api.com/json/2a01:4f9:c011:7ad7::1?fields=66842623&lang=en"
```

..  fwiw [The Windows shell quoting rules is a complete cluster fuck.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way)
I suggest switching to a unix shell (WSL? Cygwin?) instead of having to deal with [the clusterfuck that is windows shell quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way).

Unix shell quoting rules can be summarized in just a few words:

null-bytes are illegal, and wrap all strings in `'` , and replace all instances of `'` inside the strings with `'\''`.

Comment: I'm not on Windows. I'm using bash on macOS. Single or double quotation marks, neither is working. The same on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the colons. This specific API simply doesn't support TLS.
Fetching it via `curl "http://demo.ip-api.com/json/2a01:4f9:c011:7ad7::1?fields=66842623&lang=en"` works flawlessly.